# Non-markovian random walk. Elephant random walk

Tags: research-level, stochastic-processes

When one does the numerics for the usual random walk, one might use the transition matrix in order to get the probability ar time $t$ of the process. As expected, the asymptotic behavior yields a Gaussian.

There is a way to introduce non-markovianity in the process using a "microscopic" approach, dubbed the "elephant random walk" [for example here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09464v3.pdf). I'm having some trouble in reproducing the numerics for the classical case (forget about the quantum version) depicted in figure 1.

#### The dynamical rules:

The stochastic process is as follows. Suppose that the initial state is $X_0=0$ (the elephant is at the origin). At $t=1$ the elephant moves with probability $q$ to the right or with probability $1-q$ to the left.

At time $t$, the elephant has recorded if it has moved to the left or to the right from time one to time $t$, i.e. the memory is $\operatorname{mem} = \lbrace \rho_1,\rho_2,\dots,\rho_t\rbrace$, where each $\rho_i$ can be right ($=+1$) or left ($=-1$). In $t+1$, the elephant chooses with uniform probability one element in the memory, say $\rho_j$.Then it will move from $X_t$ to $X_{t+1}$ such that

$$
X_{t+1} = X_t + \rho_j
$$

with probability $p$ or

$$
X_{t+1} = X_t - \rho_j
$$

with probability $1-p$.

#### The question:

Contrary to the Markovian case, it seems cumbersome to obtain the probability distribution at time $t$ using the transition matrix. Can the probability distribution be recovered by sampling several initial "states"? By this I mean, choose $N$ initial elephants in position zero. Next evolve each elephant according to the rules and save the final position. At the end, build a (normalized) histogram from the $N$ evolved elephants. This has to yield the probability distribution of the process. Is this correct?